# Magento Cache Management Issue

Tags: magento-1.9

Whenever I flush magento cache from backend 
[image]

it redirects to login page 
[image]

How do i solve this?

Comment: Did you change base url from core config data. Also I suggest you to empty /var/cache folder manually 1 time. Because sometimes it caches before flushing it.

Comment: yes i did because i have moved site to another folder. How do i fix it, tried emptying var/cache

Answer (score 1):

You have not correct permission on folder **media**.

Please try to use from your Mage root:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 mage
```

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions